# What experience multipliers are there in Pokemon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

I know about Lucky Eggs, which [multiple experience by 2X for 30 minutes.](http://www.ign.com/wikis/pokemon-go/How_to_Level_Up_Your_Trainer)  Are there any others?

Related, but not a multiplier, you get a bonus if you visit [10 different poke stops in 30 minutes](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4w6s8t/10th_pokestop_hack_bonus/).

Comment: `if you hit 10 or more different poke stops in 30 minutes, experience doubles for a period of time` - wait what? Source?

Comment: you get double xp for [_that single pokestop_](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4w6s8t/10th_pokestop_hack_bonus/)

Comment: There are no other multipliers.  There are ways to stack XP, like curveballs and nice/great throws, and evolving or hatching a new Pokemon that is not in your Pokedex, but that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Until now there are no known experience multipliers besides the Lucky Eggs in Pokémon Go.

If you seek for Powerleveling I refer to [this guide](https://pokemongo.gamepress.gg/power-leveling).